# How to get a list of all cached audio?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

For example, my podcast app has a list of all downloaded podcast, how do I get a list of all LockCachingAudioSource that has been downloaded using request() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your `LockCachingAudioSource` instances, you can choose the location where you want them to be saved. If you create a directory for that purpose, you can obtain a directory listing using Dart's file I/O API. The directory listing will also show partially downloaded files and other temporary files, which you want to ignore. These have extensions `.mime` and `.part`.

Having explained that, here is a solution. First, create your cache directory during app init:

```dart
final cacheDir = File('/your/choice/of/location');
...
await cacheDir.create(recursive: true);
```

Then for each audio source, create it like this:

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

...

source = LockCachingAudioSource(
  uri,
  cacheFile: File(p.joinAll([cacheDir, 'yourChoiceOfName.mp3'],
);
```

Now you can get a list of downloaded files at any time by listing the `cacheDir` and ignoring any temporary files:

```dart
final downloadedFiles = (await _getCacheDir()).list().where((f) =>
    !['mime', 'part'].contains(f.path.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^.*\.'), '')));
```

If you need to turn these files back into the original URI, you could either create your own database to store which file is for which URI, or you choose the file name of each of your cache files by encoding the URI in base64 or something that's reversable, so given a file name, you can then decode it back into the original URI.

Comment: but the name extention in 'yourChoiceOfName.mp3' must be match with audio file type from uri right? because audio from uri can be m4a file or something.

Comment: It is not necessary when playing it through `LockCachingAudioSource` because it stores the Content-Type header in the `.mime` file and restores that when serving the cached file, regardless of the filename or its extension. Keep in mind also that on the web, some URLS don't have proper extensions anyway. But if you want to got this extra step, you can replace that part of my solution with a file name that puts on the extension you want.